# How to upload sample code for Adafruit M0 IoT Starter Kit?

Tags: arduino, azure-iot-hub

I am following the tutorial how to upload sample code for Adafruit M0 IoT Starter Kit available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-kit-arduino-get-started. I have completed almost all, but I have a problem with the step "Deploy the sample application to Feather M0 WiFi". I have got the following error in Arduino IDe when trying to deploy sample code to the Adafruit M0 Board:

```
D:\PROJEKTI\NavIoT\iot-hub-Feather-M0-WiFi-client-app-master\app\app.ino:5:31: fatal error: Adafruit_WINC1500.h: No such file or directory
```

I suppose problem is in libraries, because the Adafruit_WINC1500 library is deprecated, and Arduino IDE offer Wifi101 library instead. Do you know simple solution how I can run the sample code? Can I include the deprecated library? Do you maybe have some better solution how to finish the mentioned Azure IoT tutorial?

Comment: You can try [download the Adafruit_WINC1500 library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_WINC1500) and place it to path like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries

Comment: Thanks, Rita, your comment solves my problem.